# `adb shell; ps` does not list Google Chrome process id

Tags: android, adb

I want to list the process id for my app. Say my app is Google Chrome.

There are no apps open in task manager. I shell and list processes:

```
abd shell 
ps
```

there are only two processes running

[image]

Then I open Google Chrome. I do ps again, the same two processes are running, no Google Chrome.

Why not?

Answer (score 1):

Using `ps` alone is not enough. To get the full list of processes you have to use the following command

```
ps -A
```

Ps is quite flexible and provide you a lot of parameters in order to get more/less information related to active processes. The help can be shown with the `--help` parameter:

```
usage: ps [-AadefLlnwZ] [-gG GROUP,] [-k FIELD,] [-o FIELD,] [-p PID,] [-t TTY,] [-uU USER,]

List processes.

Which processes to show (-gGuUpPt selections may be comma separated lists):

-A  All                 -a  Has terminal not session leader
-d  All but session leaders     -e  Synonym for -A
-g  In GROUPs               -G  In real GROUPs (before sgid)
-p  PIDs (--pid)            -P  Parent PIDs (--ppid)
-s  In session IDs          -t  Attached to selected TTYs
-T  Show threads also           -u  Owned by selected USERs
-U  Real USERs (before suid)

Output modifiers:

-k  Sort FIELDs (-FIELD to reverse) -M  Measure/pad future field widths
-n  Show numeric USER and GROUP     -w  Wide output (don't truncate fields)

Which FIELDs to show. (-o HELP for list, default = -o PID,TTY,TIME,CMD)

-f  Full listing (-o USER:12=UID,PID,PPID,C,STIME,TTY,TIME,ARGS=CMD)
-l  Long listing (-o F,S,UID,PID,PPID,C,PRI,NI,ADDR,SZ,WCHAN,TTY,TIME,CMD)
-o  Output FIELDs instead of defaults, each with optional :size and =title
-O  Add FIELDS to defaults
-Z  Include LABEL
```